# Fetching images from the Gridview to the insertform

Tags: c#

I get an error

> Cannot convert 'string' to byte[]

I found out the problem.. the image is the issue, its not displaying in the `entry_jewelry` form after I double click any specific record on the gridview.

I have two forms:

1. View-jewelries list:  "it shows all the record of jewelry in the gridview".
2. Entry of Jewelry: "here we enter the stock ".

I tried a lot to get the image from the gridview back to the "Entry of Jewelry"

its not working please kindly help me out.

My gridview code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        S_Jewelry myForm = new S_Jewelry();

        myForm.Stock_Type.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_stock_no.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_qty.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        myForm.combo_itemk_description.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        myForm.combo_item_type.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_no_of_gems.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_gem_type.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();

        byte[] pic = (Byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pic);
        myForm.pb1.Image =Image.FromStream(stream);
        //  myForm.pb1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();

        myForm.txt_gem_weight.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_no_of_other_gems.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_other_gems.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_weight_of_other_gems.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        myForm.txt_cost.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        myForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using image source to load image

```
//save image location in gridview (C:\\folder\\image.jpg)
string pic = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
myForm.pb1.Image =Image.FromFile(pic);
```

Comment: my image is saved into the database

Comment: images are save to the  sql database

Comment: how can i retrieve images from the database. is it not possible

Comment: if you save images in database, use byte[] pic = (Byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value; only

Comment: byte[] pic = (Byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value;
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pic);
            myForm.pb1.Image =Image.FromStream(stream);     i tried with this code iits showing argument error

Comment: where did i go wrong!! plz help me i tried for more than 2 week to figure it out

Comment: error says as:  
ArgumentOutOfRangeException  : {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}

Comment: ArgumentOutOfRangeException is about cell index, does your girdview have 9 and more columns ? if it has, try replacing "CurrentRow" with "Rows[e.RowIndex] to get exactly row clicked.