# the image is not getting updated into the database or into the grid-view after the refresh

Tags: c#, sql

when i double click on the cell in the grid-view. it opens to the entry form and after i change the image to a different one and save. it says i have successfully inserted without error but its not changed to the latest image, old image is only available..

this is my update button code:

```
    private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Open();

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("Update Stock_Jewelry  set Stock_Type = @Stock_Type, Stock_No = @Stock_No , Quantity = @Quantity, Item_Description = @Item_Description, Item_Type = @Item_Type, No_of_Gems = @No_of_Gems, Gem_Type = @Gem_Type, Image = @Image WHERE  ID = @ID",conn);

            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_ID.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Stock_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Stock_Type.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_stock_no.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_qty.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Item_Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo_itemk_description.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Item_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combo_item_type.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@No_of_Gems", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_no_of_gems.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Gem_Type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_gem_type.Text;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", pic);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("You've updated successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        conn.Close();

        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where the image is coming from? You are just newing up a bunch of classes without bringing in the image.

Comment: my inserting the entry is working

Comment: this is updating entry

Comment: this is the link to my inserting entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033667/fetching-images-from-the-gridview-to-the-insertform/48033739?noredirect=1#comment83038864_48033739

Comment: If I understand, I think you just need to re-bind your data after you make changes.

Comment: which means that i must build the data again is it

Comment: what i meant was should it be the same way of inserting the file

Comment: At the time you add the parameter @Image, pic is an empty array of bytes.

Comment: i tried with this code:  command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pb1.Image; and getting an error: failed to convert parameter value from bitmap to byte[]..

Comment: and also i tried with this code::  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    pb1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray();
                } after i click the update button its says it has been updated. but the updated image is not replaced with the old one.